# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException with Json Array

Tags: jackson

I'm reading a JSON from an API, converting to POJO, performing some logic and then writing the POJO to a JSON file.

This is what the JSON input from API looks like

```
String jsonStr = "[{\"LastUpdatedBy\":\"Bug 101510: VMukkanagoudar\",\"IATACountryCode\":\"US\",\"MetroCodeBool\":false,\"AirportName\":\"Sawyer County\",\"Latitude\":46,\"CityName\":\"Hayward\",\"MajorAirportBool\":false,\"Longitude\":-91,\"StatusCode\":\"A\",\"DisplayNameLocal\":\"Hayward, WI (HYR-Sawyer County)\",\"DisplayNameInternational\":\"Hayward, WI, United States (HYR-Sawyer County)\",\"UpdateDate\":\"2009-03-06 20:44:00.0\",\"AirportCode\":\"HYR\",\"AirportID\":5396808,\"RegionName\":\"Wisconsin\",\"IdenticalMetroCodeBool\":false,\"ExternalName\":\"HYR\",\"CountryCode\":\"USA\"}]";
```

It is a JSONArray with one Json Object inside it.

The POJO looks likes this

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AirConfig {

    String airportCode;
    Integer airportId;
    Boolean metroCodeBool;

    @JsonProperty("airportCode")
    public String getAirportCode() {
        return airportCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("AirportCode")
    public void setAirportCode(String airportCode) {
        this.airportCode = airportCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("airportId")
    public Integer getAirportId() {
        return airportId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("AirportID")
    public void setAirportId(Integer airportId) {
        this.airportId = airportId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("metroCodeBool")
    public Boolean getMetroCodeBool() {
        return metroCodeBool;
    }

    @JsonProperty("MetroCodeBool")
    public void setMetroCodeBool(Boolean metroCodeBool) {
        this.metroCodeBool = metroCodeBool;
    }
}
```

I have a different @JsonProprty value on setter and getter because the name of the field when I read from API (i.e. deserialization) is different from when I write the POJO to file (i.e. serialization).

This is how I read the String

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();      
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
TypeReference<List<AirConfig>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<AirConfig>>() {};

List<AirConfig> configs = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, typeRef);

//Logic
```

But I keep getting this error -

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "airportCode" (class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate property `airportCode` and `AirportCode`, I would just add `@JsonProperty("AirportCode")` to `airportCode`:

```
@JsonProperty("AirportCode")
String airportCode;

public String getAirportCode() {
    return airportCode;
}

public void setAirportCode(String airportCode) {
    this.airportCode = airportCode;
}
```

Comment: "I have a different @JsonProprty value on setter and getter because the name of the field when I read from API (i.e. deserialization) is different from when I write the POJO to file (i.e. serialization)" - That wont work

Comment: @PranavKapoor so just replace `@JsonProperty("AirportCode")`, deserialization should be on setter, currently you expect `airportCode`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it on the read side. However, now I'm facing the same issue when I write to file

Comment: @PranavKapoor if you wanted `airportCode` when writing change getter to `@JsonProperty("airportCode")`

Comment: I made that change already. The jackson error is still the same